# Rabbitmq fails to boot

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq, celery

Rabbitmq refuses to work on my pc with the error:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========
Exception during startup:

error:{case_clause,closed}

    rabbit_networking:record_distribution_listener/0, line 366
    rabbit_networking:boot/0, line 80
    rabbit:do_run_postlaunch_phase/1, line 958

{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{case_clause,closed}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({error,{case_clause,closed}})

Crash dump is being written to: c:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/erl_crash.dump...done
```

I tried downloading the erlang and rabbitmq versions that are used in the tutorial probably the new versions had different configurations or something but i was stuck only with rabbitmq 3.10.6 from the official rabbitmq website.
So i tried my best to debug and tried checking the `erl_crash.dump` file and didn't get much from it other than random logs but got a more useful information when i checked `c:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@DESKTOP-J9C9L63.log`
the error in the log was:

```
[error] <0.380.0> epmd monitor failed to retrieve our port from epmd: closed
```

But unfortunately couldn't get anything on the error online, I couldn't find the file either. I'm trying to integrate rabbitmq with django-celery,your help will be really much appreciated.

Comment: Just an opinion. It is better to run rabbitmq on docker, so you need not to worry about all these dependencies and issues

Comment: Try disabling Windows Firewall.

Comment: It's disabled already